Simultaneous elimination of variables in multiple polynomials
I have a system of $n=O(1)$ non-homogeneous polynomials of total degree $d=O(1)$ $p_1,\dots,p_r\in \mathbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. I would like to eliminate $n-1$ variables simultaneously from the $n$ polynomials.


Is there a resultant type object for this?



I know the $n$ polynomials have common integer roots.



Will the final polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x_i]$ at some $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ (after eliminating $n-1$ variables) contain at least one integer root?




Let common integer root be of magnitude $\|(x_1,\dots,x_n)\|_\infty$. What is the complexity of the elimination process?



Elimination (in a polynomial ring) is a completely mechanical (although with horrible complexity) process. It is available is all major computer algebra systems. So I guess the answers are "no to a formula yes to an algorithm", "yes", and -- of I remember correctly -- "super exponential"

I do not think I asked for a formula. what is the resultant for simultaneous elimination of variables?

There is such a thing as a resultant for systems of multivariable polynomials, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Macaulay's_resultant – see also Peter F Stiller, An introduction to the theory of resultants, https://isc.tamu.edu/resources/preprints/1996/1996-02.pdf and https://macaulay2.com/doc/Macaulay2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Resultants/html/index.html

There is also Carlos D'Andrea, Alicia Dickenstein, Explicit formulas for the multivariate resultant, Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra, Volume 164, Issues 1–2, 2001, Pages 59-86, ISSN 0022-4049,
https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(00)00145-6.
(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404900001456)
(Abstract next comment)

Abstract: We present formulas for the multivariate resultant as a quotient of two determinants. They extend the classical Macaulay formulas, and involve matrices of considerably smaller size, whose non-zero entries include coefficients of the given polynomials and coefficients of their Bezoutian. These formulas can also be viewed as an explicit computation of the morphisms and the determinant of a resultant complex. [There's more, if you search for Macaulay resultant].

@GerryMyerson Thank you.
